# Keep data entered on html form after submit with data saved via AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an html form:

```
<form id="formfacility">
    <input type="text" id="MyName">
    <button type="button" id="btnCanxFormFacility">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmitForm">Submit</button>
</form>
```

then in javascript I have for the submit button:

```
           $("[id^='btnSubmitForm']").click(function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var btnID = "#" + $(this).attr('id');
            var formID = btnID.replace("btnSubmit", "");
            console.log(btnID, formID);
            ProcessFormSubmit(formID, btnID);
        });
```

where ProcessFormSubmit does the validation and saves the data via AJAX.

for btnCanxFormFacility, I have

```
        $("#btnCanxFormFacility").click(function () {
            let hideandreset = false;
            let HasChanges = HasLocationDataChanged();
            if (HasChanges) {
                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel and lose your changes?")) {
                    hideandreset = true;
                }
            }
            else { hideandreset = true; }
            if (hideandreset) {
                $('#FormFacility').trigger("reset");
                $("#btnCanxFormFacility").prop("disabled", true);
            }
        });
```

My issue is that when btnCanxFormFacility is clicked, it deletes all the data that was entered on the form after page load. Normally, this is what is supposed to happen with an HTML reset and would be resolved by the form posting and reloading. However, since I am using JavaScript and AJAX, there is no round trip so the form thinks all of those entries are changes, and clears them.

Is there an easy way to tell the browser not to reset any of the fields that were saved on the last execution of "btnSubmitForm"?

Perhaps I did not explain clearly.

1. The form is displayed with data from the DB.
2. The user enters or changes the displayed data.
3. The user clicks submit and all the data from the form is validated and sent to the DB using AJAX. The form is NOT refreshed.
4. The user again enters or updates data (I know, right).
5. User realizes they made a mistake so clicks cancel to clear their entries.
   The point here should be to *only* clear entries that have changed since the last submit. Unfortunately, that clears everything since page load. I know that HTML cancel is supposed to do that. But, when we are dealing with ajax, etc. that process outside the normal request/response cycle, there must be a way to deal with that.

Thanks,

Comment: try using php with: value"<?php echo $_POST[name]?>"

Comment: Side note:  to simplify your code, change the submit button to `type="button"` and then you can get rid of the `preventDefault` in your JS.

Comment: @GijsBijl - This is written in MVC. I should have added that tag. Sorry

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - That was a typo. The closing tag is there. Also, cancel and submit for fire when they are supposed to. That is not an issue.

Comment: @devlincarnate - If I do that, none of the JQuery Validation will work. Jquery Validation only works - at least automatically - on submit. So, I use the submit to validate and prevent the postback with the prevent default. Thanks

Comment: @John - you can trigger the validation.  But it's a personal preference at that point (whether you prefer to keep the submit button and let it happen automagically, or whether you intentionally trigger it)

Comment: *My issue is that when btnCanxFormFacility is clicked, it deletes all the data* - but is that what you want with a `reset()`?  If you don't want the form to reset then remove `$('#FormFacility').trigger("reset");`   Or did you mean "when btnSubmit" is clicked?

Comment: In `ProcessFormSubmit(formID, btnID);` your `formID` will be just `"#"` (given the code provided).

Comment: "*validation only works on submit*" - but the code, as provided, does *not* run a submit, it disables the submit by handling the click.   So if your validation is automatically occurring then it's likely because the submit button isn't being handled and your form is actually submitting

Comment: @devlincarnate Except that a normal submit WILL generate a request - which we do not want to do. We want to submit the data via AJAX and not do a roundtrip to the server. Isn't that the point of AJAX?

Comment: @freedomn-m. The only thing my submit does not do is fire the request. In every other regard, it is treated as a submit. And changing it ti a type="button" won't resolve the issue. The cancel is still going to clear anything added or changed since page load.

Comment: Yes, your clarification helps to target your issue away from the submit functionality.

Comment: An alternative to saving `defaultValue` is to reload your form after/as you POST it - ie the server-side post returns replacement HTML (a PartialView as you're using MVC), this could include the defaultValue so reset()ing will reset to that form rather than your original.

Comment: @John - I never suggested a normal form submit.  I suggested that you change the button to type button instead of submit because then you won't need to prevent the default action of a submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call [`reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) on a form, it restores each input's value to its `defaultValue`.

So to save an "interim" state, you need to update each input's `defaultValue` property to the current value.  Here's a solution for `input`:

```js
$("#reset").click(() => {
  $('form').trigger("reset");
});

$("#save").click(() => {
  $("input").each((i, e) => {
    console.log($(e).val())
    $(e).prop("defaultValue", $(e).val())
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name="name">
  <input name="age" type='number'>
</form>
<button type='button' id='save'>save state</button>
<button type='button' id='reset'>reset</button>
```

---

In your case you can add this at the time of `ProcessFormSubmit` - either within ProcessFormSubmit, eg if this already has code to loop inputs or before/after.

The key is:

```
$(this_input).prop("defaultValue", $(this_input).val())
```